# Mathematical statistics: Expected value, Probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

this is a problem in my math book, and I really need to know how to solve these kinds of problems, so any help would really be appreciated.

This is the problem: In a cylinder with the volume a, you pour the volume $X$ of a liquid. (If $X>a$ then of course some of the liquid will pour out.). Here X is a Random variable with Probability density function $f_X(x)=(x+1)^{-2}, x\geq 0$. Let $Y$ be the volyme of the liquid that is in the cylinder after it has been filled. Calculate $E(Y)$.

All I know is that the answer is $ln(a+1)$. I have no idea how to get there though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider $X \le A$ and $X \gt A$

Comment: How so? Could you please explain it a little? I'm not very good at this.

Comment: $\mathbb E[Y]=\mathbb E[Y\mid X \le A] \, \mathbb P(X \le A) + \mathbb E[Y\mid X \gt A] \,\mathbb P(X \gt A)$

Comment: I think I get it, but how do I know what P(X≤A) and P(X>A) is?

Comment: @Eulersfunction You have the density function of $X$, which completely describes the probability that $X$ lands in any interval.

Comment: Even better $\mathbb E[Y\mid X\leq a]\,\mathbb P(X\leq a) = \int_{0}^a Y(x)~f_X(x)\operatorname d x$ and $\mathbb E[Y\mid X> a]\,\mathbb P(X> a) = \int_{a}^\infty Y(x)~f_X(x)\operatorname d x$.  And you know what $Y$ equals in those intervals wrt $x$ and $a$

Comment: What's our Y(x)? Sorry I'm really confused here.

Comment: $Y$ as a function of $x$   (technically, ${Y\vert}_{X=x}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple partition.    $Y=X~\mathbf 1_{X< a}+a~\mathbf 1_{ X>a}$, and so Linearity of Expectation says:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) ~=~& \mathsf E( X~\mathbf 1_{X\leq a})+\mathsf E(a~\mathbf 1_{ X>a})
\\[1ex] =~& \mathsf E(X\mid X\leq a)~\mathsf P(X\leq a) + a~\mathsf P(X > a) 
\\[1ex] =~& \int_0^a x~f_X(x)\operatorname d x + a\int_a^\infty f_X(x)\operatorname d x\end{align}$$

---

NB: $\mathbf 1_{x\leq a}= \begin{cases}1 & : & x\leq a\\0 &:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\\\mathbf 1_{x> a}= \begin{cases}1 & : & x> a\\0 &:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks. Is it some standard formula to multiply the x and a by these?

Comment: In detail, $Y=X 1_{x\leq a} + a 1_{x>a}$, and then you're just applying linearity of expectation (that is, $E(A+B)=E(A)+E(B)$ for any random variables $A$ and $B$). It isn't a "standard formula", no, it's something that you have to justify somewhat intuitively from the information in the word problem.

Comment: Its the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Comment: Thanks guys, but (referring to Jack's comment) how are we justifying it from the words in the problem? if we add E(a 1X>a) aren't we adding what was poured out as well?

Comment: @Eulersfunction No, it is the volume of the container times the probability of pouring more into the container than it can hold.  That is making sure the expectation is not including the excess for any outcome where more than can be held is added. $$\mathsf E(a\mathbf 1_{X>a}) = a \mathsf P(X>a)$$

Comment: Ok, thanks I solved it, before I close this, I have another similar probem maybe you could help with? I thought it would be better to post it there than to ask a new question. The question follows: A parking is payed with a fixed charge of 10dollars and another charge of 5dollars/h is added . The time a customer has his car parked is a random variable with the Probability density function fx(x)=e^-x, x>=0. Let Y be the amount the customer pays. Calculate E(Y)

Comment: @Eulersfunction So, $Y=10+5\,X$.  Again use the Linearity of Expectation. $$\mathsf E(Y)=10 + 5\,\mathsf E(X)$$

Comment: Well what will be my upper value of integration? infinity? And the lower value is 0 I assume?

Comment: @Eulersfunction Yes.  Although it is the expected value of an exponential distribution so you should not *need* to integrate.

Comment: Thanks, I understand both solutions now, It's just one thing i can't wrap my head around to understand and that is why we add aP(X>a). Since how I figure it is that Y is the volyme of the cylinder after we've filled it,  and E(X∣X≤a) P(X≤a) is basically the expected value of it not pouring over, multiplied by the chances of that not happening, and even if it does pour over, that will not change the the volume of how much we poured in to the cylinder, will it? It can only be filled to a certain level.

Comment: It does not change the volume, but the increased weighted average of having the maximum volume "pulls" the mean value up.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you have any videos where they solve like similar assignments that maybe I would understand if I watched them or something?